# Moving a choice field in Infopath form

Tags: infopath-rules, choice-field

I have 2 lists - both containing a multi-choice field with the exact same possible selections available.

I would like to be able to use a rule within an InfoPath form to "set a fields value" from one list to the value in the other list with any/all selections that the user has checked.

Anyway to do this?

When I try to set the group value - it doesn't like it and errors with "you must select a field".  When I select the "value" field - it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

First make a connection in current form using manage connection of query type.
Select the Library or list.Now while  setting the field values in the upper part of dialog box change the connection and now you can select field value from another list.

Comment: I have tried this and whilst it works with singular fields - it fails with the choice-field.